# Изменение цвета текста в зависимости от фона

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую плагин [BackgroundCheck](http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/), для смены цвета текста в зависимости от фона. Все делаю по инструкции — подключаю плагин и прописываю:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  BackgroundCheck.init({
    targets: 'a'
  });
});
```

добавляю нужные классы в css, но в консоли выскакивает ошибка

> Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The
>   canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

В чем может быть дело? И как это исправить? Заранее спасибо

Comment: проблемы могут быть с использованием локально, попробуйте протестировать на сервере

Comment: также в интернетах пишут, что одним из решений этой проблемы является добавление аттрибута `crossDomain = "anonymous"` вашему изображению через html, либо js `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";`

Comment: действительно помогло и через сервер и через атрибут, спасибо

Comment: оформил ответом. пометьте, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием галочки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

необходимо либо проверять работу на сервере, а не локально.
также одним из решений этой проблемы является добавление аттрибута `crossDomain = "anonymous"` вашему изображению через HTML, либо используя JS: `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";`